# Create matrix of matrix by loading data "MATLAB"

Tags: matlab, loading

I want make a vector of matrix with loading data of text file.

I am using `cat`.

```
n : number of matrices.
p : number of columns of matrices.
```

every matrix has 4 row.
for example I have 1200 numbers in one text file and `p` is 3, so `n=100`.
How can make it?!

This is what I tried to do:

```
X = cat(n,[1...p; ; ; ],...,[ ; ; ; ]);
```

Comment: This is not enough information, please describe what the relevant variables and file look like and what happens when you try your solution.

Comment: The first argument in `cat` is the dimension along which you want co concatenate, not number of elements to concatenate. In your case that first argument could be 1, 2 or 3, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have numbers 1...n(1200) in one column of a txt file. i want import this data to a vector of 4*3 matrices or other dimensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is a bit vague, but here is what I would recommend:

1. Read all the data into matlab (It seems like you know how to do this)
2. Put everything in one big matrix or vector
3. Only after putting everything together, use the `reshape` command

In your case you may want to do something like this for step 3:

```
raw = rand(1200,1); %Assuming your data looks something like this
X = reshape(raw,[],4,3);
```

For 1200 values this will give you a 100x4x3 answer. Just make sure it is a nice multiple of 4x3 if you apply reshape like this.

**Update**

Apparently this was the variation the asker was looking for, a 4x3x100 matrix:

```
X =reshape(r,4,3,100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it makes three 1200*4 matrices ?!

Comment: r = 1 + (2-1).*rand(1200,1); now i want put this numbers in one hundred 4*3... X=cat(100,...) and apply for example: X(3,:,56)

Comment: @AlekMorfy If I do  `r = 1 + (2-1).*rand(1200,1);` and check `size(reshape(r,[],4,3))` it nicely gives me 100x4x3. This means you can acces it via `X(3,:,56)`. Play around a bit with the inputs of `reshape` to get what you want. --- perhaps `reshape(r,100,4,3)` or `reshape(r,100,3,4)`

Comment: r = 1 + (2-1).*rand(1200,1); X =reshape(r,100,3,4); it gives a vector of 4 matrix that every matrix has 100 rows and 3 column, i want 100 matrix with 4 rows and 3 columns so X =reshape(r,4,3,100); is okay... thanks Dennis Jaheruddin

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of matrices (n), you can store it into a cell array like this

```
myCellArray = cell(n,1);
for it = 1:n
    myCellArray{it} = (...) %Load matrix whatever how you do it (Load, fread,...)
end
```

or just by using dynamic allocation, but not really efficient,

```
myArray = [];
myArray = [myArray newLoadArray];
```

Comment: Cell arrays are mostly designed for data with irregular sizes. As here everything is nicely 4x3 (or some other regular size) it feels like a waste not to use Matrices.

Comment: After another read, I understand more he question. And you are right, cell array isn't what he needs.